# When to use Task.Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult() and ().GetAwaiter.GetResult()?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, task

I have an async Task that needs to be called synchronously (yes, unfortunately, it is unavoidable). It seems that there are two ways of implementing this - each seeming to work. So I'm unsure which is the best approach, or if there is a better one.

For example:

```
var meetings = Task.Run(() => GetTodaysMeetingsAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var meetings = GetTodaysMeetingsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If someone could explain why one approach is better than another, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: They are not equivalent. First one actually has a bug where it leaks the returned `Task`.

Comment: Please could you elaborate?

Comment: If you are on the .Net Framework `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can deadlock. But if your on .Net Core it is fine.

Comment: What is the signature of the `GetTodaysMeetings` method? If it return a `Task<T>`, then it should have the `Async` suffix. Also what is the type is of your application? Windows Forms? ASP.NET?

Comment: @FrankNielsen That only holds true for ASP.NET Core which got rid of the `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @TanveerBadar as i said, it goes for .Net Core (as Asp.Net Core is part of)

Comment: @FrankNielsen It only goes for ASP.NET Core. It does not go for the entire .NET Core.

Comment: @FrankNielsen That is entirely incorrect. .NET core is much more than ASP.NET core, the latter is a part of former, don't conflate the two. With WPF and Windows Forms coming to .NET core in 3.0, it is even more problematic that you would advice anyone to not care about deadlocks if they are on .NET core.

Comment: Ok, havent moved to the 3.0 platform yet. So is my answer correct if there is no `SynchronizationContext`/ui-thread like asp.net core, console?

Comment: It is correct for ASP.NET and console, unless someone decides to install a non-default `SynchronizationContext` in the running program.

Comment: The code is simply ran on a Console App with .Net 3, so I'm assuming the suggestion by @FrankNielsen is to be ignored?

Comment: .Net 3 is ambiguous. I guess you probably mean .NET Core 3.

Comment: Well, yes ok then.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use `Task.Run`, the initial synchronous part of your delegate is run on a threadpool thread, whereas just `().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will run that synchronous part on the same thread.

Using `Task.Run(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can be used as a workaround to run async code and wait on it synchronously, it will not result in an async deadlock, whereas `().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` could. Do be aware that it still isn't "safe", in that you likely are blocking within a threadpool thread, on servers this can lead to thread pool exhaustion at load.

If you want to run a `Task` returning method, and *know* that the initial synchronous part is trivial, and you know that the rest of the async method will not run with a `SynchronizationContext`, just `().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can be a micro-optimization, I'd say only do it if you know *exactly* what you are doing.

How do you know that you are running under no `SynchronizationContext`? `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be `null`, due to one the following reasons:

- You *know* your code is running under an application model that doesn't have one (Console app, ASP.NET Core, Windows Service)
- You have used `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on an awaited incomplete `Task` previously in the current stack.
- You have explicitly called `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null)`

So you see, it's a lot to think about, so in general you almost always want to use `Task.Run(...).GetAwaiter.GetResult()`.

Comment: For learning if you are running under a `SynchronizationContext`, you can also query the property [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current).

Comment: I'm using Net7 and have overridden `PageModel` with my own page to get stuff. The problem is that I can't use `OnGet` on the overridden page and have to use `OnPageHandlerExecuted`. I then have to use `.GetAwater().GetResult()` because my Razor page renders before an API call completes. So any model updates aren't complete so I get null exceptions. Any suggestions