I do not understand what this code is doing
I am relatively new to C#. Could someone please explain what is happening here?
public List<InboundPlanSummary> GetListInboundPlans(ParameterGetListInboundPlans parameterGetListInboundPlans) =>
    Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

I am lost here. Any help with an explanation would greatly be appreciated.

=> is a lambda operator it basically reads as  "given something, return something"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean.  My guess is the command above is setting up a task which takes a list of inbound plans and eventually returns the results Asynchronously.

Looks like an attempt to provide a synchronous version of an async method GetListInboundPlansAsync. Usually considered an anti-pattern because of the risk of deadlocks. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018541/when-to-use-task-run-getawaiter-getresult-and-getawaiter-getresult and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324300/calling-async-methods-from-non-async-code

Ok so lets attempt a small overview since theres a lot of thing coming together here

public int MethodName(int a) => a+5;


Is the same thing as

public int MethodName(int a)
{
    return a + 5;
}


So basically Method() => x; is just a short hand for return x. This is mostly used if the retrun value/its generation is a oneliner.
So lets use that knowledge to translate your
public List<InboundPlanSummary> GetListInboundPlans(ParameterGetListInboundPlans parameterGetListInboundPlans) =>
    Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

into

public List<InboundPlanSummary> GetListInboundPlans(ParameterGetListInboundPlans parameterGetListInboundPlans)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}


Now lets take a look at
Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
Too make this easier I will split theese up for you.
var a = Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans));
var b = a.ConfigureAwait(false);
var c = b.GetAwaiter();
var x = c.GetResult();

Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans)) Creates and Runs a Task. That Task executes GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans).
Since its the same Method name just with async appended we can assume/conclude that GetListInboundPlansAsync returns a List<InboundPlanSummary> but in an async way.
This means that the thing it returns isnt actually a fully filled List but a Task that is still running/filling that List.
so our a has the Type Task<List<InboundPlanSummary>>
As a quicky and for simplicities sake when you see a Task.Run(() => Meth()) ignore the () => part and focus on what comes after. If you want to execute multiple things in a task run you can do this Task.Run(() => { //write like this is just a method})
ConfigureAwait(false) in very simple terms determines that the Task/await will run on a different Thread then the Thread that called it.
so our b is a ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<List<InboundPlanSummary>>
GetAwaiter()well gets you the awaiter of the Task (its not terribly important)
and GetResult() gets the result of the task once it has run to completion and ends the Task/Awaiter
So lets say we had var result = Task.Run(() => GetListInboundPlansAsync(parameterGetListInboundPlans)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
With the knowledge we just attained we can say that it does the following:
A Task is told to queue GetListInboundPlansAsync and run it async on a different Thrread in the Threadpool ConfigureAwait(false). When then grab the awaitable GetAwaiter and extract the result GetResult so that our result is of type List<InboundPlanSummary>
And that Result is then returned.
So in very short: The Method you posted enables you to synchroniously run the asynchronious Method GetListInboundPlansAsync and get the List out of it.

"determines that the Task/await will run on a different Thread" - this is wrong. It determines that after the task has been awaited, the code may resume on a different synchronization context.

@KlausGütter ah then i apologize. From what I understood when you run it with true it has the ability to block threads, like for examples UI threads. I will gladly replace that error. Is there a way youd recommend writing it so that beginners can understand it?

The blocking you mention is an effect of using GetAwaiter().GetResult() waiting for the task to complete while the task waits for continuation on the same thread. See e.g. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
